# How to access buttons on a parent form from a child form which inherits it

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance

I made a Windows Form in VB.NET that has a Panel with a Datagridview on it, and underneath it a FlowLayoutPanel with Save and Close buttons on it, call it frmParent. Then I created frmChild and on it I inherited frmParent. I then hooked up my DataGridView to some data and it worked fine.

Next I tried to add code to save changes to the datagrid and the buttons are locked. I checked the modifiers: both buttons and the FlowLayoutPanel that contains them are Protected. I read that there are frequently problems accessing controls that are contained in a collection of another control. But the DataGridView is fine, so my question:

What do I need to do to get the Save and Cancel buttons to be available on the child form? Do I need to do away with the FlowLayoutPanel, or is there another way? In this simple example it isn't that big of a deal, but I would like to start using visual inheritance regularly and I would like to know the best way to do things.

Comment: you are seeing the "Locked" indicator for controls implemented on the parent when working with the child form in the IDE, right?  and you want to be able to do stuff in the child form with some of those controls?

Comment: Correct. But none of my fiddling has got me around those locks.

Comment: so, you want the same controls on multiple children, but each child needs to implement them differently perhaps? (e.g.  SaveFoo, SaveBar, SaveCustomer ...)

Comment: Exactly so. I try to contain my business/engineering logic as well as my database machinations in their own class, so forms just have to worry about display stuff. There is a great variety of information to be examined and edited, and I wanted to be able to use this form in conjunction with the different classes involved.

Comment: *personally*, I would have a dedicated FooForm, BarForm etc which is "owned" by the FooClass; as such the form would be the expert on  displaying Foo while the class would handle the bus logic and db stuff.  but you can expose the base form stuff...

Comment: In most cases, that is exactly what I will do, because certain subjects just will not have enough common elements to be worth it. Just kicking this form inheritance thing around to see how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
Public Class frmParent

    Private Sub Button_SaveClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ButtonSaveClicked(...) ' pass here any argument you want (e, sender, anything...)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub ButtonSaveClicked(...)
        ' Do here what frmParent should do upon Button_Save Click...
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class frmChild
    Inherits frmParent

    Protected Overrides Sub ButtonSaveClicked(...) ' same arguments
        ' Do here what frmChild should do upon Button_Save Click...
        ' Eventually call MyBase.ButtonSaveClicked(...)
        ' if you want frmParent to act aswell...
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

**EDIT : For the following parts of the question** :

- dissociating user interface and object datas
- passing an instance of the object or not ?

I'm no expert on programming, but I've read one interresting thing about that user interface/object.

What come to my mind first talking about user interface is a blog post (don't recall the link, sorry) talking about `Windows way` of programming and `Linux way`. Before starting to drift to an off topic ride, I want make clear that I don't care about linux vs windows and I'm not interrested in such debate. Just want to share what I remember from this blog post :

*In windows programming, the first thing you usually think of (and invited to do) is to create an user interface : the windows form (or the window in WPF) Then you'll create the objects that will be manipulated through that interface. In linux programming, it's the inverse : you'll create first the objects with everything they should be able to do, and only after you'll think of the user interface that will "enhance" the way to manipulate them.*

^^ Or alike.. I'm zero linux knowledge, so I can't compare, but I assume the above is true, mostly. And I reckon that since OOP existed, this "windows way" of programming (that I'm used to) has a lot of drawbacks and messy code : you're constantly asking yourself wether a specific part of the code should be enclosed in the object or in the user interface.

So, I've come to an idea of mine, it may be stupid, but I'm fine with. I started to try that "linux way"... at least, *"the way I'm thinking a linux programmer does it"*

---

Let's take that control called `DataGridView`. It can contain text, dropboxes, buttons, images, etc. I'm not digging in bounding Dataset to keep it simple. Basically, the DataGridView is an object having everything to manipulate the above sub-objects within it. Unfortunately, a `String`, or an `Image` is not a (visual) control, while a `dropbox`, or a `button` is. You have a typical case of windows created object (DataGridView) that is a melting pot of datas and user interface, but you don't have an object that handles only the data part of the DataGridView, and another object that handles only the visual user interface of the thing (or at least, I'm not aware of such objects in .Net) AFAIK **You're forced to handle *both* data and user interface when using a DGV !**

So I created a class and simply called it `Table_Class` that can contain such objects (***that are not controls***) like String, Bitmap, List (of String), XML... almost anything as the contained datas are binary coded.

Then I created a Form, and called it `Table_Form`, that can display the content of a `Table_Class`. But almost all edits are functions and methods that are members of the Table_Class. If I want to order the grid by columns, it's the class that does it through one of its inbuilt function.

Of course, I'm not here to show that I'm wasting my time to reinvent the wheel, I know I'm doing it wrong but this approach is required by the fact I'm dealing with a massive amound of various datas loaded **from files** and saved **as files**. I'm just glad I have my own class of datas and happy to extends its capabilities **when I want**.

The main purpose of this blabla is to illustrate my opinion about passing an **entire class** or **some of its members** to a form. In this tandem Table_Class/Table_Form, of course, I'm passing the entire Table_Class on the Table_Form and vice versa. In fact, it's two different thing that can be used at the same time, or one at a time :

```
' SAMPLE CODE : Entire classes takes several files...
Public Partial Class Table_Class
' here is the object that is invisible to the user
    Private _ContainerForm As Table_Form = Nothing

    Public Sub ShowForm(Optional ByVal OwnerForm As Form = Nothing)
        If _ContainerForm Is Nothing Then
            _ContainerForm = New Table_Form(Me)
        End If
        If OwnerForm Is Nothing Then
            _ContainerForm.Show()
        Else
            _ContainerForm.Show(OwnerForm)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByRef NewContainerForm As Table_Form)
        _ContainerForm = NewContainerForm
        _ContainerForm.SetTable(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is the (associated) Form (constructor and associated Object initialization)

```
Public Partial Class Table_Form
    Private _SelectedTable As Table_Class = Nothing

    Public Sub SetTable(ByRef NewTable As Table_Class)
        RemoveHandlers() ' Table_Class has events.
        ' If _SelectedTable is not Nothing,
        ' remove handlers prior to redefining a new selected Table.
        _SelectedTable = NewSelectedTable
        _SelectedTable.SetContainerForm(Me)
        InitializeHandlers() ' Add all handlers for UI updates upon Table_Class edits.
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByRef NewSelectedTable As Table_Class)
        SetTable(NewSelectedTable)
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I can manipulate the Table_Class either in the background when the user shouldn't care about its content, or via a user interface. With a DataGridView, you must take care of all the visual appearance in order to build an output to the Data/DataSet/Database.

What is important to note here is **from the moment you want a visual display of an object through an user interface, you MUST pass critical members of that object to the displaying interface**. You can't avoid doing it at a moment or another. In my example, I've passed the ENTIRE Table_Class since I'm doing every data modification in that class.

The difference with a DataGridView is :

- with a DGV, when you edit one (String) entry in a Cell using KeystrokeOrF2, the Value is stored in that Cell of that DGV, then, either your application directly sends programatically the value to the associated Database, either you have a save button or a save menu to update the edits.
- With my Table_Class, of course I'm using a DataGridView to display its contents, and I have a save button on a toolbar and in a menuitem. But when I click on those buttons, the `Save` method is not in my Table_Form Form. The Save Method is a method belonging to the Table_Class itself.

That's an example where lies the separation between the visual interface (of the DataGridView/Form) and the object actually containing the datas.

I know this Table_Class/Table_Form example is a complex one, but the way I understand half of the secund part of your question **in your original post** is : *"how do I separate user interface and data/object manipulation"*

**The answer** : it's up to you !
I think we have similar ways of doing it : my `Table_Class` does everything as your `BlackBox` Class. My `Table_Form` shows the datas and your Parent/Child Form so does.

I assume the remaining half of your issue is : *"I can't call BlackBox.SaveChanges from the Click method of my button when it is in the FlowLayoutPanel"*. That's not related to the Object/User Interface limits syndrome, and is an entirely different issue. That's the main purpose of this answer before this long edit : I suggested a workaround by calling a method (`ButtonSaveClicked()`) instead of writing the save part of the code direclty under the `Button_SaveClick()` method that handles the click. I don't know if this approach worked for your "locked" button or not.

Back to the user interface/object thing : So comes the above : *"you must pass critical members of your object to the user interface at a certain point"*, and that critical member must be an object (with the critical datas you want to manipulate, in this case, I assume the data to save) In my Table_Class/Table_Form example, I've passed the entire Table_Class in the Table_Form :

```
Public Partial Class Table_Form
    Private _SelectedTable As Table_Class
    ' ...
End Class
```

so when I want the Table_Class (object containing data to manipulate) to save edits, **through the table Form** (form acting as an user interface) I have those methods sets in the Form :

```
Public Partial Class Table_Form
    Private Sub Menu_Main_File_SaveClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' MenuStrip -> File -> Save
        SaveTable()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ToolBar_Main_SaveClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' A Save Button shortcut on a toolbar.
        SaveTable()
    End Sub

    ' ^^ Both controls calls the same method SaveTable()
    ' This is similar to the ButtonSaveClicked method I initially suggested
    ' What SaveTable does ?

    Protected Overridable Sub SaveTable()
        If _SelectedTable IsNot Nothing Then
            _SelectedTable.Save(True)
        End If
        ' It just calls the Table_Class.Save(... arguments)
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

In the end, the code handling how the datas should be saved doesn't exists in the user interface. To save changes, the Table_Class object has a handfull set of Save(...) methods that handle extension like SaveAs (opens a SaveFileDialog), Overwrite without Prompt, Save as binary or save as textual... And if I want more extensions like sending the datas on the web, in a database, or even packing/unpacking the table contents in a directory, all I have to do is to implement that in the Object (Table_Class) and only the visual part will be handled in the form, the same way I did it from the start.

So when you ask me "*Wouldn't I end up with child-specific code in the parent form that way?*" I would say : "it's up to you". I've decided that the Table_Class does everything : data loading/parsing, data updating **and data saving**. If at a time in the future I have to implement a new way of saving the datas, I have the choice to add an overload of the Save() method of my Table_Class, or building a specific Save method in another form for another application using my Table_Class if I want. And that's possible because the Table_Class :

- is not an User Interface
- has an associated user interface in case it's required
- while it has everything to read from and write datas to, programmatically.
- and yes, **I'm passing the entire Table Class** in the UI, no matter it's a parent one or a child form that use inheritance.

I think "having messed parent/child code in your user interface side" highly depends on the capabilities of your non user interface object that (should) manipulate the datas.

(Actually, the Table Class is not a single Table. It's the Node of a Tree of Tables, or a Table that contains datas, and Tables children that contains other datas each. You can think of it like the merger of a DataGridView and a TreeView, that's why the Private variable un the UI Form is named _SelectedTable.)
I'm mentioning that last complexity of the Table_Class to clearly notify that no matter how complex the object is, it's easy to use whatever the user interface you use, because there isn't a single visual code in the object, and there is very little code manipulating datas in the user interface (all the UI does is to read datas from the object, display/edit or use them for other purposes, and send the validated modifications to the object, then call Object.Save())

---

I've made a long explaination of the way I'm doing it to let you have the latitude to decide how you want your application to behave, what your `BlackBox` class should be able to achieve **alone** and what are the limits of your user interface. There is no simple answer to that analysis, and highly depends on who is going to use your application for what purpose; if you have deadlines, keep it simple, but if your goal requires complex and highly manipulable datas, *I think* you should not mix user interface code and data manipulation code; this is a hell to alter if you have to upgrade your class with new features at a later time.

Sorry for the long post. I'm french speaking and I don't know if my english is okay. Don't mind the blabla, that's just me, can't keep an idea in my mind without telling it in details.

Try the ButtonSaveClicked() call workaround. That worked for me with a flow layout panel : I've made an Overridable ButtonSaveClicked() in the parent Form with a message box saying "Hello", and an Override ButtonSaveClicked() in the child Form saying "Coucou", and it worked well.
Then you can create a variable containing your BlackBox object in the parent form like I did with my Table_Form, and a way to make it accessible from the child form (Protected, or Public Property or a set of Protected methods and functions, I don't know...) Then decide what would be your BlackBox members (properties, methods, functions, events...) and how they should/could be used from the parent and the child forms.

Comment: Suppose I have an instance of a class called BlackBox with property BlackBox.Data as Datatable and method BlackBox.SaveChanges. I can already set dgvData.Datasource = myBlackBox.Data and that works.  Would I have to pass the entire instance myBlackBox to the parent form so it could call myBlackBox.SaveChanges? Wouldn't I end up with child-specific code in the parent form that way?

Comment: I don't understand well. A child class inherits the members of a parent. If you define a method .SaveChanges() in parent (higher level than Private) then child class has also the same method (that is initially the parent's one) unless you use Overridable in the parent class and redefine that method in the child one using Overrides. The arguments in ButtonSaveClicked I suggested above is there to get ANY required information in the child class from the parent, not the inverse. The purpose of Overrides is to forget about the parent class and do everything at child class level.

Comment: I probably didn't express myself  well. BlackBox is neither parent nor child but the class where I do everything not related to displaying the information. The SaveChanges method I wanted to call in the click event of the Save button. But for some reason, I am not able to handle that event on the child form in its original panelled condition.

Comment: I've edited my post to try to give my opinion about the whole thing. To be honest, I don't know what your BlackBox class does, but it seems to me you want to "encapsulate" in that class everything not related to user interface. The SaveChanges problem due to the FlowLayoutPanel is a localized issue IMHO. Anyway, if there's anything worth a try from what I wrote above, then go ahead. Otherwise, feel free to give details on a specific issue. :)

Comment: Thank you for the extraordinary amount of thought and effort you have put into this question. It will take me some time to digest your writings but I wanted to immediately acknowledge your post. I am really struggling with programming in general and OOP in particular, but you are right: BlackBox is to encapsulate everything that doesn't directly involve putting stuff in controls. And the FLP thing is apparently just a quirk: I took the buttons off of it in the parent form and got the behavior I need. But I will still look through your stuff because I need to learn.

Comment: HA ! Just remembered a tiny thing that can make a difference for the FlowLayoutPanel : The Click event in your Parent Form, like `Protected Sub Button_SaveClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`, is there something like `Handles Button_Save.Click` on the same line, or you have something like `AddHandler Button_Save.Click, Address Of Button_SaveClick` in another part of your code ? If it's the first scenario, try to add a `WithEvents` keyword in the declaration of your Button : `Protected WithEvents Button_Save As Button = Nothing`. That may make a difference in redefining it in the child form

Comment: That sounds like a very worthwhile thing to pursue - I really do like to use flowlayout panels. I will post the result of my pokings when I get time to explore this idea.

Answer (score 1):

To expose an action on a base class control as an event (another answer shows how to do this via an overridable method):

Base Form:

```
Public Event SaveClick As EventHandler

Protected Overridable Sub OnSaveClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent SaveClick(Me, e)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OnSaveClick(e)
End Sub
```

Child Form:

```
' the event will show up in the event list like any other
' this may be what you want if each child form is supposed to do everything
Private Sub Form1_SaveClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SaveClick
   ' save some stuff
End Sub

' hybrid where the child form does some stuff, base form does some stuff
Protected Overrides Sub OnSaveClick(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnSaveClick(e)              ' base form activities

    'save some stuff

End Sub
```

So the base form could raise some abstracted events like `SaveItem`, `NewItem`, `DeleteItem` and the child forms act on that much like how an interface works.

---

The flaw in this approach is that the controls are still locked on the BaseForm, as they should be (controls are Friend).  Each child *could* pass a parameter to the base form indicating a "mode":

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("Customer")
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

But to make use of it means that the base form has to have logic to handle all those various "modes" which negates the value of inherited forms specialized to handle Foo, Bar, Customer etc.  So, I am not sure form inheritance is what you want: the controls described seem too specialized.

Comment: What I did in order to move on was to "unpanel" everything and use anchoring to handle resizing. Once I did that, I was able to set the modifiers on the buttons to Protected - actually, they were set that way before. With the panels removed, I was able to handle the click events from the child form - meaning that I can now use that form for different but similar purposes, which is what I was after. I am still leaving the question open for a little while because I am hoping somebody will know how to make this happen while still using panels, which I like.

Comment: I am not sure inheritance is what you want or need.  `Yoda` inherits from `Jedi`, so he has all the traits of `Jedi` **plus** some unique to him.  If the base form is not doing the same thing in all cases for all those who derive from it, inheritance might not be the answer.  It might also simply be that the ops this base form is supposed to do could be abstracted/generalized so you pass it an object and it goes to work on the common (Jedi) things then passes the result back to Yoda or Obi Wan.  The answers here answer the question asked but that seems not to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, both from a functional standpoint and design standpoint, is to create events in your child form, i.e. `OnSaveRequested` and `OnCancelRequested`. In your parent form, declare your child form using `WithEvents` and create handlers for those events. When you want to save from the child form, raise the `OnSaveRequested` event and handle it in the parent form (same with Cancel).

Of course, in this scenario your parent form will need to know *what* to save, so you can either pass the data in as an argument to the event or expose a public property to the data in your child form.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I wonder, first, if that would make the parent form too specialized to use in many different situations but I will think long on that and, second, if doing this would add a level of complexity to the parent form that would take away from its time saving nature. I de-panelled this one, so I can have my way with the buttons, but in future it sure would be nice to use panels.